# How to use gcc options --wrap=symbol in class method

Tags: c++, gcc

This is a simple example that can help me print `malloc` params value

```cpp
void *__wrap_malloc(size_t size)
{
    printf("My malloc function!\n");
    return __real_malloc(size);
}
```

But I want to use in class method, like that

```cpp
class A{
public:
    void test(int a)
    {
        printf("%d", a):
    }
}
```

This using type gives an error.

```cpp
void A::__wrap_test(int a)
{
    printf("wrap");
    return A::test()
}
```

Can someone tell me how to use it correctly?

Comment: I guess this would help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: Study about `extern C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to use it correctly?

To use at all, you first have to have a symbol. So first move the inline function definition to be non-inline so a symbol may be generated for it. Then you need to find the mangled name of the symbol. So first correct your typos and compile the library to an object file:

```
// a.hpp
class A {
public:
    void test(int a);
};

// a.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.hpp"
void A::test(int a) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

After compilation check the generated mangled symbol name:

```
$ g++ -c a.cpp && nm a.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T _ZN1A4testEi
                 U printf
```

So here you can finally get the name of the symbol to wrap: `_ZN1A4testEi`. Then you can create the wrapped handler.

I am **guessing** most probably incorrectly that the first argument to a member function will be a pointer to the class - I did no research on the topic and I do not know if this is true. After getting the symbol name, we can write the main program:

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

extern "C" {
void __real__ZN1A4testEi(A *t, int a);
void __wrap__ZN1A4testEi(A *t, int a) {
    printf("wrap ");
    return __real__ZN1A4testEi(t, a);
}
};

int main() {
    A().test(5);
}
```

and compile&run with:

```
$ g++ -c -o a.o a.cpp
$ g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
$ g++ -Wl,--wrap=_ZN1A4testEi a.o main.o -o main.out
$ ./main.out
wrap 5
```